# Is MaxCPUCount parameter works for MSBUILD to build Delphi projects?

Tags: delphi, msbuild

`MSBuild` has parameter `MaxCPUCount`.  Is this parameter works for Delphi project groups (`.groupproj`) or projects (`.dproj`) ?  I don't see any performance improvement using `MaxCPUCount` for my build.

Answer (score 2):

The `MaxCPUCount` parameter has no impact when building Delphi project files, `.groupproj` or `.dproj`.

However, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660413/issue-with-using-msbuild-with-maxcpucount-option/3671330#3671330#3671330) suggests that you can make your own overall msbuild project file that enables parallel building.

Some more useful links:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2007/04/26/building-projects-in-parallel.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651793.aspx
- [Visual Studio 2010, how to build projects in parallel on multicore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849004/visual-studio-2010-how-to-build-projects-in-parallel-on-multicore)